# How to access value of dynamic variable in freemarker?

Tags: freemarker

I have a gradle configuration file which contains the configuration in key-value pair. 
e.g.

```
aws.codedeploy.FunctionalEC2TagKey = "functionalEC2TagKey1"
aws.codedeploy.CapacityEC2TagKey = "capacityEC2TagKey1"
```

I would like to read this configuration at Freemarker end and assign the value to the variable.

However, which key-value to be retrieved is conditional and is driven by a freemarker variable "${stage.displayname}"

Now, lets assume -
${stage.displayname} = "Functional" 
then aws.codedeploy.FunctionalTagKey should be fetched

So,
What I would like to try is

```
key   =  "${aws.codedeploy.${stage.dispalyname}EC2TagKey}"
```

and it should return "functionalEC2TagKey1"

I tried tweaking it like,

```
EC2_TAG_KEY ='${' + "aws.codedeploy.${stage.displayName}EC2TagKey" + '}'
```

and then,

```
key   = "${EC2_TAG_KEY}"
```

It's evaluating to

```
key = aws.codedeploy.FunctionalEC2TagKey
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Many Thanks,
Swapnil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be `${aws.codedeploy[stage.displayName + "EC2TagKey"]}`, or the equivalent `${aws.codedeploy["${stage.displayName}EC2TagKey"]}`, whichever you prefer. That's because `foo.bar` is the same as `foo["bar"]`, and inside the `[]` you can have any kind of expression, not just a simple string literal.